Connecting to crates.io safely, in Windows work computer, through a corporate proxy
I use cargo on a Windows 10 machine, through cmd or Git Bash. However there are some troubles with commands like this:
$ cargo search serde -vv
error: failed to retrieve search results from the registry at https://crates.io

Caused by:
  [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: CRYPT_E_NO_REVOCATION_CHECK (0x80092012) - La función de revocación no puede comprobar la revocación para el certificado.)

$ curl https://crates.io
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: CRYPT_E_NO_REVOCATION_CHECK (0x80092012) - La función de revocación no puede comprobar la revocación para el certificado.

On Settings>Network and Internet>Proxy>Automatic proxy settings I found an organization-set file named "http://10.[].[].[]/proxycompany.pac" file. I downloaded this file through a browser, its contents are:
ProxyCompany="PROXY 10.[censored].[censored].[censored]:3128;";
NoProxy="DIRECT";

function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    if (dnsDomainIs(host,".corp")) {return ProxyCompany;}
    else {return NoProxy;}
}

Doing
set CARGO_HTTP_CHECK_REVOKE=false
cargo search serde -vv

did work but it looks like a security risk unattended.
I ran the px package in case it helped with the proxy.
$ python -m px
Serving at 127.0.0.1:3128 proc MainProcess
Serving at 127.0.0.1:3128 proc Process-1

While this was running I tried to run the cargo and curl commands without the CARGO_HTTP_CHECK_REVOKE hack, but it doesn't work either.
